# Is there a Property Dialog control that i can use in my WPF App?

Tags: .net, wpf, properties, controls, propertygrid

I'm building an application using WPF that will be a designer of sorts, meaning, a user can drag and drop custom UI elements into a canvas and be able to configure their behavior via properties.

(Think of this like a domain specific PowerPoint. You can add elements to the presentation, configure the elements' properties and then eventually you can run the "slideshow" and those elements will behave according to their properties)

So in my app, what is the best way of showing and configuring an element's properties? Is there a Property Dialog control I can use? (similar to the one in Visual Studio for controls)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sadly, there is no `PropertyGrid` control in WPF. Either you will have to use WinForms property grid or one available in open source community or buy from 3rd party vendors. You have following options to choose from -

**Open Source -**

> WPF Property Grid:
>   http://wpg.codeplex.com/
>
> PropertyTools (previously called PropertyEditor) for WPF: 
>   http://propertytools.codeplex.com/
>
> Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid:
>   https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid
>
> Native WPF 4 PropertyGrid
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87715/Native-WPF-4-PropertyGrid
>
> WPF PropertyGrid - MVVM techniques:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PropertyGridMVVM.aspx

In case you are working on .Net 4.0 you can use WWF's `PropertyInspectorView` control as property grid in WPF. As explained in this article - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/WpfPropertyGrid.aspx

**3rd party :**

> Actipro:
>   http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/wpf/propertygrid
>
> ComponentOne:
>   http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PropertyGridWPF/
>
> Mindscape:
>   http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/WPFPropertygrid/
>
> Syncfusion:
>   http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/property-grid

**Custom -**

In Case you want to build your own `PropertyGrid`, have a look at these articles -

> (Very) simple WPF PropertyGrid in 20
>   minutes: http://blog.joachim.at/?p=36
>
> Your own PropertyGrid in a couple of hours:
>   http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!448.entry

Comment: There's another rich WPF property control here: http://propertytools.codeplex.com, and one in the Exended WPF Toolkit: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Thanks Govert. Looks like PropertyEditor project got renamed to PropertyTools, other option also looks good. Added them in the answer for better visibility.

Comment: @John Cummings: Thanks for updating the link for 'Extended WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid'