# Storing properties of objects in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, properties

I'm allowing user to drag/drop some objects from a toolbox and of course each `object` has a unique id. As soon as object is used, let's say placed on a `grid` or `canvas`, I need to show its properties so I need an array of objects where each object can hold its own properties.

Can you give me some advice and direction on how to implement a class to handle multiple objects while each object can hold on to let's say 10 properties?

Comment: You need to give more details about the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you want a List of objects. Or possibly a Dictionary if you want to access each object through it's unique key.

Comment: Either use an ObservableDictionary within you classes or a WPF PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a `PropertyGrid` control; your application looks similar to Visual Studio and your implementation will be similar to that.

Have a look at this SO question for available `PropertyGrid` options you have -
[Is there a Property Dialog control that i can use in my WPF App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800416/is-there-a-property-dialog-control-that-i-can-use-in-my-wpf-app/3801711#3801711)

Now you can define a class for each control and declare normal CLR properties for that control; properties you don't want to display in PropertyGrid can be marked with [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) and PropertyGrid will honor that.

In case you want more control over what properties are displayed, you can create your own [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and modify PropertyGrid implementation to use that attribute and display properties marked with this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you give me some advice and direction on how to implement a class
>   to handle multiple objects while each object can hold on to let's say
>   10 properties?

There is no need for you to implement such a class. The way I would handle this problem would be to have a common base class for all the objects in the toolbox (`ToolboxItem` for example) which only exposes properties and functionality common to all items in the toolbox.

```
public abstract class ToolboxItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Point Position { get; set; }
}
```

You can then derive your specific items from this class E.G. `TextToolboxItem` and `RectangleToolboxItem` (or whatever you want). The derived classes can then expose only the properties they require.

```
public class TextToolboxItem : ToolboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class RectangleToolboxItem : ToolboxItem
{
    public Rect Bounds { get; set; }
}
```

To store these you could just use a generic collection such as:

```
ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem> items = new ObservableCollection<ToolboxItems>();
```

As long as the items derive from `ToolboxItem` they can all be held within the single collection and the individual properties can all be bound to using WPF's data binding features.

You can then create and expose the data in the following way:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        items = new ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem>
        {
            new TextToolboxItem { Name = "primaryText", 
                                  Text = "Hello world", 
                                  Position = new Point(40, 130) },
            new TextToolboxItem { Name = "secondaryText", 
                                  Text = "Hello world (again)", 
                                  Position = new Point(200, 30) },
            new RectangleToolboxItem { Position = new Point(50,300), 
                                       Name = "Rect1", 
                                       Bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 150, 85) },
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ToolboxItem> Items { get { return items; } }
}
```

To display this information in the user interface I would do the following:

- Use a grid to split the view into two sections. The first is where the properties of the selected item will be displayed and the second displays the 'design surface'
- Use a `ContentPresenter` to display the properties of the **selected** item.
- Use a `ListBox` with a custom `ItemsPanel` and `ItemContainerStyle` to 'draw' your items onto the design surface.
- Use a `DataTemplate` to tell WPF how to render each item in both the 'property grid' and the 'design surface' ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114865/577417) post describes how to use a different `DataTemplate` for different objects).

The xaml required to achieve this is shown below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
                      Margin="5">
        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:TextToolboxItem}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:RectangleToolboxItem}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bounds}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
    </ContentPresenter>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="1"
             Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:TextToolboxItem}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"
                         Margin="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:RectangleToolboxItem}">
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Bounds.Width}"
                           Height="{Binding Bounds.Height}"
                           Stroke="DarkRed" Fill="Pink"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the properties of the selected item are shown in the left hand section of the window.

Now this solution is currently very crude but does demonstrate a starting point for you to develop this further. Ideas for improvement include:

- Re-factoring the code into a viewModel so that it is MVVM compliant.
- Handling drag and drop of the items on the 'design surface'.
- Changing the `ContentPresenter' for a property grid to give you much richer support for displaying and editing the properties of the selected object.